# YouTube JSON Pagination (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, youtube, pagination

I'm trying to create a function that load 15 new results and append them below the results previously loaded with jQuery, is there a way?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    startindex = 1;
    loadmore = 15;

    src = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=games&alt=json-in-script&max-results=12&start-index=" + startindex;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: src,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
                var list = [];

                $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, e) {
                    list.push([
                        '<li class="video">',
                        '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + e.id.$t + '/default.jpg" />',
                        '<a href="' + e.link[1].href + '">',
                        '<span>' + e.title.$t + '</span>',
                        '</a>',
                        '<span>' + e.author[0].name.$t + '</span>',
                        '</li>'
                    ].join(""));
                });

                $("#list").html(list.join(""));
            }
        }
    });

    function loadMore() {
        var startindex = parseInt(startindex) + parseInt(loadmore);
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: You need to increment the start-index and then append the newly fetched results to the bottom of your list. What seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is convert most of the code inside your `$(document).ready()` into a standalone function, which you then call inside `$(document).ready()` instead. That function will take two arguments, the start position and the total number of records.

The start position is easily obtained by counting the number of items already in your `<ol>`, and the total number of records being fetched will (presumably) never change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  startindex = 1;
  loadmore = 15;
  addMore(startindex, loadmore);

  $('#addmore').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addMore($('#list li').length, 15);
  });
});

function addMore(startindex, loadmore) {
  src = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=games&alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + loadmore + "&start-index=" + startindex;

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: src,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
        var $list = $('#list');

        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, e) {
          $list.append('<li class="video"><a href="' + e.link[1].href + '"><span>' + e.title.$t + '</span></a><span>' + e.author[0].name.$t + '</span></li>');
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
ol {
    list-style: decimal;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="list"></ol>
<a href="#" id="addmore">Add more</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/PC6dn/1/